# R XML package: how to set the user-agent?

Tags: r, user-agent, libxml2

I've confirmed that R calls of XML functions such as htmlParse and readHTML send a blank user agent string to the server.

`?XML::htmlParse` tells me under `isURL` that "The libxml parser handles the connection to servers, not the R facilities". Does that mean there is no way to set user agent?

(I did try `options(HTTPUserAgent="test")` but that is not being applied.)

Comment: There's nothing obvious that I can see in the documentation or the code for `htmlParse`.  You might be better contacting Duncan Temple Lang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XML::htmlParse` uses the libxml facilities (*i.e.* NanoHTTP) to fetch HTTP content using the GET method. By default, NanoHTTP does not send a User-Agent header. There is no libxml API to pass a User-Agent string to NanoHTTP, although one can pass arbitrary header strings to lower-level NanoHTTP functions, like `xmlNanoHTTPMethod`. Hence, it would require significant source code modification in order to make this possible in the XML package.

Alternatively, `options(HTTPUserAgent="test")` sets the User-Agent header for functions that use the R facility for for HTTP requests. For example, one could use `download.file` like so:

```
options(HTTPUserAgent='BioStatMatt-via-R')
download.file('http://biostatmatt.com/', destfile='biostatmatt.html')
XML::htmlParse('biostatmatt.html')
```

The (Apache style) access log entry looks something like this:

```
160.129.***.*** - - [01/Sep/2011:20:16:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 4479 "-" "BioStatMatt-via-R"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. By the way XML::htmlParse() will take a character string, saving the need for a temporary file. But download.file() insists on saving to a file. Is there an alternative function to download a file directly into a character vector?

Answer (score 5):

Matt's answer is entirely correct. As for downloading to a string/character vector,
you can use **RCurl** and `getURLContent()` (or `getForm()` or `postForm()` as appropriate).
With these functions, you have immense control over the HTTP request, including being able to set the user-agent and any field in the header. So

```
 x = getURLContent("http://biostatmatt.com", useragent = "BioStatMatt-via-R", 
                      followlocation = TRUE)
 htmlParse(x, asText = TRUE)  # or htmlParse(I(x))
```

does the job.